# How can i return '0' from query in pgsql, if the row doesn't exist?

Tags: postgresql

How can i return '0' from query in pgsql, if the row doesn't exist?
Like

> SELECT IF EXISTS(field) THEN field ELSE 0 FROM table

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't completely understand what result you want to get, but if you want to get value from a field from some row in a table and 0 if there's no rows, try:

```
select coalesce((select field from table limit 1), 0)
```

if you have some filter condition for table which could return 1 row or nothing, try this query:

```
select coalesce((select field from table where <your condition>), 0)
```

Comment: actually, my second variant a bit different from Magnus Hagander's one. In my solution you'll get value from the table and in his solution you'll get 1 or 0, don't know which one you want to get.

Comment: I will get field value instead of '0' of course) I didn't see it

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE xxx) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

But your question talks about exists on a *field* not on a row. If you're just comparing to NULL, and considering that "if it exists", it'd be:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN field IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM table
```

(And of course, if you actually want '0' the string, just put single quotes around the return values.