# Return 1 if number exists in table and 0 otherwise

Tags: sql, postgresql, boolean, exists

I want to return 1 if some number already exists in table and 0 otherwise.

I tried something but it doesn't work:

```
select
case when 100 in (select distinct id from test) then '1'
else '0'
from test
```

I want something similar to exists function that already exists in PostgreSQL, but instead of `true` and `false` I want `1` or `0`.

Comment: I found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309293/how-can-i-return-0-from-query-in-pgsql-if-the-row-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**[`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS)** yields a `boolean` result.
The simple way to achieve what you are asking for is to cast the result to `integer`:

```
SELECT (EXISTS (SELECT FROM test WHERE id = 100))::int;
```

`TRUE` becomes `1`.
`FALSE` becomes `0`.

See:

- [Return a value if no record is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098795/return-a-value-if-no-record-is-found/8098816#8098816)

**Or** with `UNION ALL` / `LIMIT 1` (probably slightly faster):

```
SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE id = 100
UNION  ALL
SELECT 0
LIMIT  1;
```

If a row is found, `1` is returned and Postgres stops execution due to `LIMIT 1`. Else, `0` is returned.

**Disclaimer** for the `UNION ALL` solution: this relies on **undocumented behavior** that Postgres would execute `UNION ALL` terms in sequence. This used to be the case until Postgres 11, where `Parallel Append` was added to Postgres. It's actually still the case (currently Postgres 15) for the given example, as retrieving a single row will never trigger a `Parallel Append` plan. But it remains undocumented behavior, so you might not want to rely on it. See:

- [Are results from UNION ALL clauses always appended in order?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/316818/3684)

Comment: I'm having a tough time understanding why UNION ALL works here, but UNION does not

Comment: @NoobException: `UNION ALL` simply appends rows to the result - and immediately stops as soon as `LIMIT` is satisfied. `UNION` is a completely different beast: it takes rows from all branches, sorts (or hashes) to eliminate duplicates, and only then considers `LIMIT`. It just so happens that duplicates would not matter for `LIMIT 1` but there is no special code path for that corner case.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The problem here is UNION ALL doesn't guarantee order (same way as UNION doesn't), so it can return random values with this approach.

Comment: @vladich: The SQL standard does not guarantee order, but the Postgres implementation does for this simple form with `UNION ALL`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter No it doesn't. I came across an example where it does it in the opposite order. Postgres documentation also says:
```UNION effectively appends the result of query2 to the result of query1 (although there is no guarantee that this is the order in which the rows are actually returned). Furthermore, it eliminates duplicate rows from its result, in the same way as DISTINCT, unless UNION ALL is used.```. UNION here refers to both plain UNION and UNION ALL.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter. In most cases it will return the result in the natural order, but unfortunately there is no guarantee of that, so using this approach is very dangerous.

Comment: Basically, if the first query is too expensive (and second is simple something like SELECT 0 in your example), Postgres can decide that it's not worth to execute the first one and instead choose the second

Comment: @vladich: I would be most interested in that example you came across. As I have yet to see one. And I have tried.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I don't think it would be easy to reproduce, because it comes with a lot of data (the tables involved contain tens of millions of records).
Basically, the example looks like this:
>SELECT true FROM ..... JOIN ...
>UNION ALL
>SELECT false
>LIMIT 1;
First ```SELECT``` is expensive, has a single JOIN and returns about 3.7 millions of rows.

Comment: If you modify it like 
```(SELECT true FROM ..... JOIN ... LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT false
LIMIT 1;```
it returns true.
If you modify it like
```SELECT true FROM ..... JOIN ...
UNION ALL
SELECT false WHERE 0=0
LIMIT 1;```
it also returns true. But simply saying, the order is not guaranteed.

Comment: @vladich: Postgres uses an `Append` step in the query plan, and that doesn't change with the cost of each branch. I suspect there was some kind of misunderstanding. The examples in your last comment don't support your claim. I'll be a believer if you show me. (I don't think you can.)

Comment: @vladich: This is important enough to justify a [question on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/316818/3684). You may be interested.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter In my case a ```Parallel Append``` is used which can execute child plans simultaneously.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yeah, I doublechecked the other two cases where it returns data in "right" order, those plans use ```Append```, for the opposite order case ```Parallel Append``` is used. That may give you an idea how to reproduce it.

Comment: If I disable ```Parallel Append``` with ```SET enable_parallel_append = false```, it starts returning results in the expected order

Comment: @vladich: `Parallel Append` is a likely suspect, indeed!

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Do you want to edit your answers? I understand in 2014 (another one in 2011) when it was answered, it held true (although relied on undocumented behavior), but currently it doesn't.

Comment: @vladich: I added a disclaimer accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7):

If the field you are testing is the Primary Key (or some other unique constraint), then you can simply return the count (which will always be 0 or 1):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM test WHERE id = 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

it easy and quick:

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE id = 100), 0) res
```